# How to implement a working confirmationDialog in The (Swift) Composable Architecture 1.0

Tags: swift-composable-architecture

In pre 1.0 TCA, there was relatively straightforward was to present a ConfirmationDialog

- scope the `Store` in a View modifier to the `State` property holding an optional `ConfirmationDialogState` struct.
- provide a dismiss action

When the optional was populated with state (e.g. made non-nil), the dialog would appear

```
.confirmationDialog( store.scope(state: \.deleteConfirmationDialog), dismiss: .authAction(.dismissLogoutConfirmationDialog))
```

But this code does not compile in 1.0. What's the new syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For TCA 1.2.0 you can use this code for your View:

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
       WithViewStore(self.store, observe: { $0 }) { viewStore in
           HStack {
              Button("Show Confirmation Dialog") {
                  viewStore.send(.showConfirmationDialog)
              }
           }
           .confirmationDialog(
                    store: self.store.scope(
                        state: \.$destination,
                        action: { .destination($0) }),
                    state: /YourDomainFeature.Destination.State.confirmationDialog,
                    action: YourDomainFeature.Destination.Action.confirmationDialog
                )
       }
    }
}
```

And in your reducer file YourDomainFeature.swift

```
struct YourDomainFeature: Reducer { 
    struct State: Equatable {
        @PresentationState var destination: Destination.State?
    }

    enum Action: Equatable {
        case destination(PresentationAction<Destination.Action>)
        case showConfirmationDialog
        enum ConfirmationDialog: Equatable {
            case cancelTapped
            case yourButtonOptionTapped
        }
    }

    var body: some ReducerOf<Self> {
        Reduce { state, action in
            switch action { 
            case .showConfirmationDialog:
                state.destination = .confirmationDialog(.showConfirmationDialog())
                return .none
            case .destination(.presented(.confirmationDialog(.cancelTapped))):
            // Do something when cancel button is tapped
                return .none
            case .destination(.presented(.confirmationDialog(.yourButtonOptionTapped))):
            // Do something when your button option is tapped
                return .none
            case .destination(.dismiss):
                return .none
            }
        }
        .ifLet(\.$destination, action: /Action.destination) {
            Destination()
        }
    }
}
extension YourDomainFeature {
    struct Destination: Reducer {
    
        enum State: Equatable {
            case confirmationDialog(ConfirmationDialogState<YourDomainFeature.Action.ConfirmationDialog>)
        }
    
        enum Action: Equatable {
            case confirmationDialog(YourDomainFeature.Action.ConfirmationDialog)
        }
    
        var body: some ReducerOf<Self> {
            Reduce { state, action in
                return .none
            }
       }
    }
}

extension ConfirmationDialogState where Action == YourDomainFeature.Action.ConfirmationDialog {
    static func showConfirmationDialog() -> Self {
        ConfirmationDialogState(title: TextState("Dialog Title"), buttons: [
            .default(TextState("Button Option Title"), action: .send(.yourButtonOptionTapped)),
            .cancel(TextState("Cancel"))
        ])
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://www.pointfree.co/episodes/ep247-tour-of-the-composable-architecture-1-0-correctness for explanation of the above strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Note: basic familiarity with TCA is assumed. Extensive tutorials are at https://www.pointfree.co

To get `confirmationDialog` View modifier working with TCA 1.0 syntax, the below code compiles and works. It may not be ideal, as the TCA guys have not covered best-practices with `confirmationDialog` yet. It requires implementation of `PresentationState` and `PresentationAction` semantics.

in `Feature / Reducer`

```
struct State: Equatable {   
     @PresentationState  var logoutAndDeleteDialog: ConfirmationDialogState<Action>?
...
}
```

Use a dedicated case to 'namespace' all actions that might be sent from the `ConfirmationDialogState<Action>` buttons. (Those actions get automatically embedded in a `.presented` case when sent to the parent Reducer from the ConfirmationDialogState view. More on that later.)

```
enum Action: Equatable {
        case logout(PresentationAction<Action>)
case deleteData(Bool)
. . .

}
```

Create a `ConfirmationDialogState` struct to display the confirmation view. Add any desired `Action` buttons to the `buttons` property.  (There may be a better way to do this: I used a property in the reducer.)

```
  let conf: ConfirmationDialogState<Action> = { var conf =  ConfirmationDialogState<Action>(title: {TextState("Logout")})
        conf.buttons = [ButtonState<Action>(action: .deleteData(true), label: {TextState("Logout and Delete Data")})]
        return conf
    }()
```

The `ConfirmationDialogState` View sends `Actions` to the `Reducer` via buttons. (In this instance, a .deleteData Action button is created in the ConfirmationDialogState initializer above.)

That `Action` must be caught in `Reducer` `switch` statement as an an associated value of a .presented case.

Where did the invisible `.presented` case come from? It's a result of annotating the `ConfirmationDialogState` with `@PresentationState`. This automatically embeds all Actions sent by a `ConfirmationDialogState` in a `.presented` case. The exception is the .dismiss action, which *not* embedded.    (Tricky, and not necessarily intuitive.)

There is likely some overarching logic the TCA guys are trying to enforce in separating Parent Actions from Child Actions. With confirmationDialogs, this logical separation is handled by embedding `ConfirmationDialogState` actions in a `.presented` case, making explicit that any actions coming into the reducer are from a Child-type view.

```
reduce(into state: inout State, action: Action) -> ComposableArchitecture.Effect<Action>
switch action {

//note that `.deleteData` Action has been wrapped first in `.presented`, then in `.logout`. `.presented` because the dialog is marked with a PresentationState property wrapper, and `.logout` because in the View below the `Store` is scoped to embed actions local to the dialog into the .logout Action case, found in the parent Reducer. This is all a little mind-bending. At least it was for me.

case let .logout(.presented(.deleteData(bool))):
            //handle data deletion

//unexpected behavior if I did not include .dismiss in switch statement and nil out confirmationDialog state manually
  case .logout(.dismiss): 
            state.logoutAndDeleteDialog = nil

...
}
```

in View with Store

n.b. the dialog state keypath name must be precded by $, //e.g.  .$logoutAndDeleteDialog

This is due to the @PresentationState property wrapper being added to the ConfirmationDialogState-type property. So the wrapper, and not the value, is being accessed by the architecture in the `scope` method.

```
Text(vs.userName).confirmationDialog(store: store.scope(state: \.$logoutAndDeleteDialog, action: {.logout($0)}))
```

Comment: Hi Gereon, I'll try to clean this up. Since TCA / Pointfree guys have not yet covered this in their series, I just threw something together to help if someone else got stuck. I don't yet have excellent insight into PresentationState and PresentationAction, but this code compiles, and works.